# New Facebook SDK issues: "terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException"

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, user-interface, facebook-graph-api

So with the updated Facebook SDK to enable a user to login to my app, I seem to not be able to get it to work properly! I am using code based off of Firebase's guide since that is what I am trying to integrate it with.

I am getting frustrated with it and cannot get the below error to stop terminating my app. I have all of the proper .plist info entered, I have the cocoa pods installed, and all of the SDK folders that are required. PLEASE HELP!

My code displays no errors, but when I build and run and then click on the Facebook button I get: "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb) "

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit


class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func fbButtonPressed(sender: UIButton!) {

    let facebookLogin = FBSDKLoginManager()

        facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], fromViewController: self) { (facebookResult: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, facebookError: NSError!) -> Void in

        if facebookError != nil{
            print("Facebook login failed. Error\(facebookError)")
        } else {
            let accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString
            print("Succesfully logged in with Facebook. \(accessToken)")
        }
    }
}
}
```